# same file name in multiple directories: how to assign them with different names at the same time with only one command?

Tags: rename

I have 23 different directories and in each one of them I have a file called accepted_hits.bam

so I need to generate a unique name in each directory: e.g
accepted_hits.bam_1 for directory 1
accepted_hits.bam_2 for directory 2

and so on 23 times. Is there a easy way to do that with a single command?

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` and `find`

```
find . -type f -name accepted_hits.bam -exec bash -c \
'i=0; for f; do (( ++i )); mv -- "$f" "${f}_$i"; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: this renames all the files as `accepted_hits.bam_1`. I was also going to post a similar one but then noticed the counter does not get incremented for each file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your directories are all at the same parent, try this:

```
$ for f in $(ls */accepted_hits.bam); do mv $f $(dirname $f)/$(dirname $f)-$(basename $f); done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `awk`, but that's just a matter of taste, not of right and wrong:

```
find . -name accepted_hits.bam | awk '{ print "cp -pi \"" $0 "\" \"" $0 "\"_" NR "; mv -i \"" $0 "\"_" NR " ./bam-files/" }' | tcsh -f
```

where you need to create a directory `./bam-files/` before calling above line, or adjust the directory name.  I have intentionally used `-p` for preserving file times and `-i` for avoiding overwrites, just in case.  So, before calling the commands for a 2nd time please clean the target directory.

If you wish to remove the original files please replace the `cp -pi` by `mv -i`.

The script leaves out calls to `basename` in the hope to run into less trouble if the pathname contains special characters (spaces and most special characters are handled).

PS: You could also do a dry-run before executing by leaving out the `| tcsh -cf` at the end.  If you do not have `tcsh` installed (yes, there are Linuxes without it) feel free to use `sh` or `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would just like to name them as unique files, you can use the `RANDOM` variable as below:

```
find /basedir/ -type f -name "accepted_hits.bam" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 $0.$RANDOM' {} +
```

If you would like to sequentially name them, you can append a counter value at the end of the filename as below:

```
for file in $(find /basedir/ -type f -name "accepted_hits.bam"); do ((count++)) ; mv $file ${file}_${count}; done
```

The above two methods rename the file in the same directory. If you'd like to rename them to a different directory, you can combine them with @schlimmchen's answer ( using basename and dirname ). You can even insert an echo statement before the move command to see the result without actually moving the files. I've found it a handy way to test the commands without risking any changes to the files.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy do to with shell globs:

1. Add a counter to the name (`accepted_hits.bam.1`, `accepted_hits.bam.2` and so on):

   ```
   c=0; for f in */accepted_hits.bam; do mv "$f" "$f".$((++c)); done
   ```

   #### Explanation

   This simply iterates over all files called `accepted_hits.bam` that are in subdirectories of the current directory, and saves each of them as `$f`. The `$((++c))` construct increments a counter (`$c`), so `$f.$((++c))` will be `file.1`, `file.2` etc, incremented on each iteration.

   Note that I am using `c=0` at the beginning. If you don't do this, subsequent runs will keep the value of `$c` and it will keep incrementing.
2. Add a counter but before the extension (`accepted_hits.1.bam`, `accepted_hits.2.bam` and so on):

   ```
   c=0; for f in */accepted_hits.bam; do  
       mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")"/"$(basename "$f" .bam)".$((++c)).bam
   done
   ```

   #### Explanation

   The command `dirname` returns the path to a file's parent directory:

   ```
   $ dirname /usr/local/bin/apt 
   /usr/local/bin
   ```

   The command `basename` is the inverse, it removes the directory, leaving only the last part of the path and can also remove an extension:

   ```
   $ basename /etc/apt/sources.list
   sources.list
   $ basename /etc/apt/sources.list .list   ## remove extension
   sources
   ```

   So, `mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")"/"$(basename "$f" .bam)".$((++c)).bam` will rename the file as desired.
3. Add the parent directory's name (`accepted_hits.dir1.bam`, `accepted_hits.dir2.bam`, or whatever your directory names are)

   ```
   for f in */accepted_hits.bam; do  
       dir="$(dirname "$f")"; mv "$f" "$dir"/"$(basename "$f" .bam)"."$dir".bam
   done
   ```

   #### Explanation

   This is the same idea as above, only I am saving the directory's name as a variable to simplify using it as part of the file name.
4. Use external tools. Perl `rename` for example. The standard `rename` that ships with Debian-based distributions can't deal with incrementing counters. However, I found [this one](http://www.volkerschatz.com/unix/uware/rename.html) which can. Download the script linked to in that page, save it as `increname` in your current directory and run it like this:

   ```
   perl increname -n 's/.bam/++$c . ".bam"/e' */accepted_hits.bam
   ```

Comment: @don_crissti the OP hasn't said that the directories are numbered, so I don't see any other way to do it. I don't see how you can be so sure as to say that's definitely not what the OP wants. How do you know that the directory names contain numbers? In fact, since these are .bam files, the directories are probably names after chromosomes and include chrx and chry.

Comment: @don_crissti actually, since these are .bam files (a common format in bioinformatics) the directories are probably names `chr1` through 22 and chry. Hence my solution using the directory name. Can't know unless the OP clarifies though.